# My apk asks for permissions that I am not asking for on my AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, apk, android-permissions

I just noticed that my app is requesting new permissions all of the sudden.

```
./aapt d permissions MyApk.apk 
package: mypackage
uses-permission: android.permission.INTERNET
uses-permission: android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
uses-permission: android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE
uses-permission: android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
uses-permission: com.android.vending.BILLING
uses-permission: android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
uses-permission: com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT
uses-permission: android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
uses-permission: android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS
uses-permission: android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
uses-permission: android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

I believe these 3 are things I'm not requesting:

```
  uses-permission: android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
  uses-permission: android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS
  uses-permission: android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
```

These are the only permissions on my AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

This is an app I've been releasing new versions for at least once a month for well over a year, this is the first time this has happened.

I recently switched to using MoPub but I didn't change my permissions, plus I released that version over a month ago. The most recent thing I did was add the ChartBoost jar file but that is just a  jar file.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: may be `ChartBoost ` may be wanting those permissions

Comment: `that is just a jar file.` Which may require the additional permissions.

Comment: MoPub may have it's own permissions

Comment: Like I said I already added the MoPub a while back and the permissions weren't there. ChartBoost is the new one but it is just a jar. The MoPub module does not have permissions on the AndroidManifest.xml but I'm not even sure if those matter if they were actually there.

Comment: Think I figured it out. All my play services gradle dependencies were 7+ and 7.5 just came out. I changed them to 7.3 and that fixed the issue. 7.5 must be changing permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of my Google Play Services dependencies were 7+ and 7.5 just came out last week so it must be requiring the new permissions because when I changed them to 7.3 it all started working like normal again.

After the 7.3 change:

```
uses-permission: android.permission.INTERNET
uses-permission: android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
uses-permission: android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE
uses-permission: android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
uses-permission: com.android.vending.BILLING
uses-permission: android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
uses-permission: com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT
```

This is the change I made:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7+'
```

To:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.3+'
```

I did it to all my Google Play Services dependencies so I don't know if ads is the only one requiring that or if it is all of them.

EDIT: From my testing, as soon as you add `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:7.5+'` to a clean project, it will start requiring those new permissions.